# Apple TV zoom/stretch (Netflix app)

Tags: appletv, 4k

What gestures or buttons make the Apple TV in Netflix app zoom/stretch the image to fill screen?

On the Apple TV 4K (2017) using Netflix app, I somehow zoomed/stretched an old tv show with nearly-square aspect-ratio to fill the screen of this 4K TV.

Only the Apple TV remote was in use at the time. Seems to have happened when I swiped my thumb on the touch surface rightward from left edge, but I'm not sure.

Workaround: Crash the Netflix app and relaunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Double-tap + Swipe

Quote from [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/appletv/comments/7eckp2/aspect_ratio_conversion_gesture_in_youtube/) (emphasis mine):

> I've been running into this accidentally and thought it was a bug: 4:3
>   videos would zoom up (proportionately) to 16:9 from time to time while
>   working the remote. It turns out there's an (AFAIK) **undocumented
>   gesture: *double-tap + swipe*** left (or right). So, whenever you're
>   viewing 4:3 content, you can tap, tap and swipe left to zoom up to
>   16:9 and repeat the gesture to go back to 4:3. Neat & hope it helps
>   someone. There's quite a bit of old conference talks in 4:3 out there.

I can't explain it any better than that, but hopefully it helps.